# Can hreflang be placed on the body of the HTML?

Tags: html5, hreflang

Can `hreflang` be placed on the `body` of the HTML? Or has it to be in the `head`?

I can't find clear information about this.

Comment: It's clear as day if you read the specification.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Google supports:

- [Link Hreflang](https://www.w3.org/wiki/Html/Elements/link)
- [HTTP Header Hreflang](https://www.askapache.com/htaccess/#Charset_Language_headers)
- [Sitemap Hreflang](https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/2620865?hl=en)

Using `<link rel="alternate" href="#" hreflang="en-ie" />` within the `<body>`and not the `<head>`, testing it in W3C validator fails and reports the following:

> [W3C](https://validator.w3.org/#validate_by_input)
>
> A link element must not appear as a descendant of a body element
>   unless the link element has an itemprop attribute or has a rel
>   attribute whose value contains dns-prefetch, pingback, preconnect,
>   prefetch, preload, prerender, or stylesheet

It has been mentioned by [Rob](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/users/8466/rob) and [Boldewyn](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/users/14335/boldewyn), in both answers and comments that hreflang can be used within a `<a>`, since these tags are allowed within the body. This is true and both users make good points, however...

*It can be very complex using hreflang within `<a>` and its unclear if its supported by Google:*

1. You need to make all links to page use the markup, so if you have many articles interlinking one another, it can become complex, very complex if having more than 2 language options. Adding markup to the page rather than links is less complex because you simply do a GET URL and plant that variable into link canonical, link hreflang, Facebook opengraph, Twitter cards etc.
2. The main issue however is Google's Search Console Help mentions nothing of using `<a>` for Multiple languages, this isn't to say its not supported, its just that I can say for sure it is.

*Google specific says it supports:*

> HTML link element in header. In the HTML  section of `http://www.example.com/`, add a link element pointing to the Spanish
>   version of that webpage at `http://es.example.com/`, like this:
>
> ```
> <link rel="alternate" hreflang="es" href="http://es.example.com/" />
> ```
>
> HTTP header. If you publish non-HTML files (like PDFs), you can use an HTTP header to indicate a different language version of a URL:
>
> ```
> <http://es.example.com/>; rel="alternate"; hreflang="es"
> ```
>
> To specify multiple hreflang values in a Link HTTP header, separate the values with commas like so:
>
> ```
> <http://es.example.com/>; rel="alternate"; hreflang="es">, <http://de.example.com/>; rel="alternate"; hreflang="de">
> ```
>
> Sitemap. Instead of using markup, you can submit language version information in a Sitemap.

*I recommend that you verify your MARKUP on-going using [W3C validator](https://validator.w3.org/#validate_by_input), for example using this direct input code:*

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Simon Hayter Rocks!</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="example.css">
    <script src="example.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <link rel="alternate" href="http://example.com/en-ie" hreflang="en-ie" />
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: This is not true. You can place `@hreflang` equally well on `<a>` elements. The specification: https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/links.html#attr-hyperlink-hreflang

Comment: And the W3C version: https://www.w3.org/TR/html5/textlevel-semantics.html#the-a-element

Comment: @Boldewyn Browser vendors have all defected to WHATWG, for HTML at least, unfortunately. Use WHATWG as a reference.

Comment: @Rob Google supports `<head><link></head>`, HTTP Header or Sitemap and at no point does it say it will support BCP 47 tags.

Comment: @Rob updated answer

Comment: @Rob no one “defected.“ Also if you'd read carefully, you've seen that I posted the link to the WHATWG spec in the first comment. In this specific case, though, they match literally word-by-word (§4.5.2 of WHATWG text, §4.8.2 of W3C text).

Comment: @Boldewyn You have it backwards. It is the W3C who has the WHATWG text word-for-word. (Even so, that is not true either.) It is an unfortunate split from the computer scientists of the W3C for the cool kids of WHATWG. https://github.com/w3c/charter-html/issues/112

Answer (score 2):

**No.**

The only Link elements permitted in the `<body>` section are ones that are specified in the 'body-ok' list. You can find a copy of the table here:
https://www.w3.org/TR/html5/links.html#body-ok

Answer (score 1):

You can use `hreflang` as attribute on both [`<link>`](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/semantics.html#the-link-element:attr-hyperlink-hreflang) elements and [`<a>`](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/links.html#attr-hyperlink-hreflang) elements exclusively. So, in a nutshell, no, you cannot short-circuit by putting `hreflang` on the `<body>` (like you could, e.g., with `<base>` for relative URLs).

Example in the page header, referencing an alternate language version for search engines:

```
<head>
  <link rel="alternate" href="?lang=en" hreflang="en">
</head>
```

Example in the page body, clickable by users:

```
<body>
  <a rel="alternate" href="?lang=en" hreflang="en">View this information in English</a>
</body>
```

Comment: The `area` element can also have the `hreflang` attribute.